FilePicker extension Flutter problem with custom types
Here is my code :
  FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
      // TODO: check if this is really true
      // This solution of filtering does not work, because the package is ignoring custom extensions like "scd".
         type: FileType.custom,
        allowedExtensions: ["scd"],
    );

Here its to pick files with extension scd.
PS we have scd files in phone because we saved them using same APP.
I cant pick any files , it thrown an error:
Reloaded 1 of 1670 libraries in 1.288ms (compile: 26 ms, reload: 569 ms, reassemble: 469 ms).
W/FilePickerUtils(10325): Custom file type scd is unsupported and will be ignored.
D/FilePickerUtils(10325): Allowed file extensions mimes: []
I/flutter (10325): [MethodChannelFilePicker] Platform exception:
PlatformException(FilePicker, Unsupported filter.
Make sure that you are only using the extension without the dot,
(ie., jpg instead of .jpg). This could also have happened because
you are using an unsupported file extension.  If the problem persists,
you may want to consider using FileType.all instead., null, null)

I didnt try any other solution because I wanted to use file picker.
Any solution or a workaround ?
Greetings.

I know it's not optimal, but you can work around this by allowing all file types, and then check if the chosen files have all the correct extension. Have you tried checking their github on the issues page? Seems like your code should work as it is

Thanks for answer. This is for a client app and picking all files dosent satisfy us. Any otehr Plugin to use that allows that?

@il_boga what do you think?

Sorry, I don't know any other package for that, I've only used file_picker in my apps, but with "usual" extensions like PDF or JPEG. It's pretty strange though that FileType.custom will work only with supported extensions, but there's no list of which extension are allowed.

Weird.I checked 4 other packages and all of them dont work. Its like they are using the sameAPI calls.
